# vb Cannot run program on another computer

Tags: database, vb.net

I have made a program using visual basic 2010, which contains a database. When I copy my program across to another computer and attempt to debug it, I get the following error message:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Login failed for user 'Aaron\Aaron'.

And the following line of code is highlighted within the form load sub:

```
 Me.Table1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet1.Table1)
```

When I publish the program it also fails to run on any computer other than the one I created it on.

Any help would be much appreciated as I'm still very new to programming, thank you.

Comment: Check you connection string.

Comment: What kind of database?  Is there a server?  How does your app connect to the db?

Comment: If I open the database explorer and go to modify connection on the database1.mdf file and test the connection it fails. It is an SQL server database file.

Comment: The database is either going to be a server running on another computer - in which case you need to access that, or running on the local computer. Copying the files to the client computer won't do the trick for you. It sound like you want to install SQL Express on the client. Here's a link to it to get you started. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx

Comment: If this is a light weight application that just uses a local DB, and not a shared server, consider using SQL CE or another similar self contained DB that runs fully in the application process and does not require a server or installed service.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to access the database over the network, use:
server="HostMachineIP\Aaron" (e.g. "10.1.1.1\Aaron") and make sure firewall port 1433 is open.

If you're transferring the database to another system, set your connection string to: ".\Aaron" - the .\ references the local system.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. The database is located in the application's files that have been copied across to the other system. How do I set the connection string? Apologies if i sound stupid, I am very new to all of this and so my knowledge is very limited.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of things that could be the issue, but for starters, you probably don't have the same user set up on your other computer that you had on your first one.  That is probably why you are getting the error about Login failed for Aaron/Aaron.

Additionally, you may well have a database on the first computer that is not on the second.  Transferring the program does not copy the database with it.  So you should go into SQL Server on your first computer and compare it to SQL Server on your second one.  Likely there are differences in users and databases that will cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for your help, how would I go about setting it up so the users are the same? or so it accepts this computer's user? thanks

Comment: You should be able to create users in SQL Server on the machine.  You can find step-by-step instructions for doing this on the web based on the specific version you are using.  Ideally, the "users" section on the new machine will end up looking like it does in the old one.

Alternately, you can create a user on the new machine and change whatever configuration you are using to use the new user (it is likely in a connection string in your app.config).

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds like maybe you aren't using a "server" yet.
You won't have much luck if you are moving/copying the .mdf file.  Your dev environment will allow this, but not other machines.  It will work better if you install SQL Express on one of your machines and use it to host your .mdf (database file).  That machine will be your "server".

1. Download SQL Server Express and install it
2. Download SQL Server Management Studio.  Use it to attach your .mdf.  Set permissions.  Allow remote connections.
3. Check your windows firewall (on the server) to make sure port 1433 is open (SQL server communicates across a network on port 1433.
4. Each machine (except for the server) will need to authenticate to the server.  I find this is easier when I map a drive to the server.  On the server, make a folder on the hard drive called "temp", share it to the network.  On each machine, explore the network, find your server, find the share (temp), map a drive to it.

Once you have done these things, then these other recommendations will work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I shall attempt this and see if I can get it working. thanks.